# JWebPane cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I am having troubles with javafx , eclipse keeps showing this error :

```
 Description    Location    Resource    Path    Type
 JWebPane cannot be resolved to a type  line 20 Browser.java    /web 
browser/src Java Problem
```

I am not sure where I have went wrong and the error does not show until I compile the app.
here is my simple code :

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Browser {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine eng = browser.getEngine();
    eng.load("http://google.com");
    VBox vb = new VBox();
    vb.getChildren().add(browser);

    Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 500, 200);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

   }

}
```

Comment: `JWebPane` does not even occur in the java file. Try *clean & build* or eclipse equivalent. Your code won't work the way it is btw: you need to launch the toolkit before using javafx...

Comment: tried that before didn't work, what do you mean by launching the toolkit ?

Comment: Proper startup of a javafx application using `Application.launch` or `Platform.startup` (java 9+)...

Comment: I have tried to create a new project and copied the code to it , and I'm getting the same error @fabian

Comment: Not working with eclipse, but afaik you need to install some kind of addon or tell it to use the javafx part of the java libs somehow. Not sure if e(fx)clipse is still the way to go... Did you do this?

Comment: I have installed e(fx)clipse earlier for a different issue but it didn't work with that issue and as it is already installed and I'm getting this error I think it is not the solution for this too.

Comment: Are you using java >= 9? If so do you use the correct modules?

Comment: yes I'm using java 10 , what do you mean by correct modules (sorry I'm a biggener in java)?
and by the way I have noticed that in the console I'm getting this error 
Internal graphics not initialized yet
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens
 , so I think it is not really JWebPane but eclipse was wrong

Comment: You need to require this module to use `WebView`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx.web-summary.html Furthermore the javafx lifecycle is a bit different to other programs, see this example. `Platform.startup` would be a workaround that doesn't require subclassing `Application`, but it's seldom used.

Comment: it worked , thanks!